# Saving State for EditText and Button Clicks

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, android-button

I have 2 Activities. First `Activity` has `EditText` and `Next Button`. Second `Activity` has one `Back Button`. In First `Activity` I entered some texts in `EditText` and I hit `Next Button`. Now I'm in `SecondActivity`, If I press `Back Button` it will return to `First Activity` clearing the `EditText` fields. I want that `EditText` field to remain same. How to achieve these steps?[image]

FirstActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
EditText text;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

 CharSequence sequence = text.getText();
 outState.putCharSequence("savedText", sequence);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 CharSequence sequence = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText");
 text.setText(sequence);

 }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class Second extends Activity {
Button b;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, HomeActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

  }
```

Comment: You have to use sharedprefrence for that

Comment: okayy.. Let me try using SharedPrefernce

Comment: Thanks! It works using SharedPreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, when you want to retain the values of your MainActivity, you just need to finish the SecondActivity instead of creating new intent for HomeActivity like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, HomeActivity.class);
    //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //startActivity(i);
    //JUST FINISH THIS (SecondActivity) ACTIVITY
    finish();
}
```

This will close the second activity perminently, and Android Acticity Stack will show the previous activity with all its data.

In the more complex scenarios, when you have complex navigation between activities and still want data to retain in fields, you need to use [SharedPreferances](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), save data when you want (idealy when navigating to other activity) and load again (in onResume()) when you get back to this activity.

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: Thanks! Its working. And i have to do like this right?? `protected void onResume() {
  
  super.onResume();
  SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("etValue", text.getText().toString());
  editor.commit();
 }`

Comment: Great, lets have a tip...it is usually prefered to create two methods in you activity like saveActivityValues() and loadActivityValues(), and just call them when you need. It becomes handy when you are having more than one values to save and load in you activity. Also use some static constnts on resource strings that hold the name of your data-keys like "etValue" in this case. All to make your code more readable and manageable..:)