# How to load the values for edittext fields when back button is pressed

Tags: android, navigation, load, back

I have three pages for user registration. I implemented this using intents.For each page I have next button to navigate to next page.I have to save all the details at the 3rd page when clicking the submit button.I have back button in action bar to go forth to the pages.Its all working fine. But now my problem is when I go back to the pages it shows empty fields.But I want to know how to make that fields to be filled.Can anyone help me out for this?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` and `onResume()`

Comment: Show us some code... you should try [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17408998/2345913)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872882/saving-state-for-edittext-and-button-clicks

Comment: Are you finishing the activity when moving to next activity by pressing to next button

Comment: @AmitGupta yeah I completed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with `finish()`

While moving from 1st activity to 2nd activity, don't call finish().In 2nd Activity while clicking back menu just call finish()

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.back_btn: //your back btn id
                   finish();

            }
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: I add the back button in action bar...Sorry to ask this..How can I code for that?

Comment: @Uday action bar like menu?

Comment: @Kalai...Yeah it is in menu